# Is it possible to print infinite strings to a text file c#

Tags: string, text-files, infinite

I have been wanting to know if it is possible to print infinite strings to a file for a while now. I have found that just puting it in a while loop like bellow doesn't work, as it just prints the string once.

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("file.txt");
while(true)
{
   sw.WriteLine("hello");
   sw.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
while(true)
    using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("file.txt", true))
       sw.WriteLine("hello");
```